# Pear Installation Error in wampserver

Tags: php, windows-8, pear

I'm trying to setup pear in my wamp server.but i'v got this error.

```
PEAR_Config::writeConfigFile fopen('C:\Windows\pear.ini','w') failed (fopen(C:\W
indows\pear.ini): failed to open stream: Permission denied)
```

how can i fix this?